# sqlite savepoints in java

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to connect an sqlite database to a java code using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar driver which you can get from this list of xerial drivers [[https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads][1]](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads%5d%5b1%5d)

my understanding is SQLite supports savepoints 
but when I try to make one `connectionName.setSavepoint(savePointName);`the driver throws an sqlexception

> unsupported by SQLite: savepoints

I want to use the savepoint for bulk inserts

my question is why is this happening as it should support savepoints and rollbacks?

also is there a reason not to make it this way? if there is what other way should I use?

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: As best I can tell, that JDBC driver for SQLite does not support savepoints, even if the underlying database does: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/src/2dc282210b7d/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java?at=default#cl-633

Comment: any suggestions as t what I should do instead of savepoints?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use cases? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am inserting multiple records (around 100) at a time but I wan o be able to rollback o a certain point (for example the last 25 records) without losing all my data

Comment: Have you tried regular transactions?

Comment: In terms of rollback-supported operations, I think your options are transactions and savepoints. You'll either have to (1) do savepoint management manually, (2) find a driver that supports savepoints, or (3) use transactions.